# How to return only one value in the field and not all the values ​in the django table?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want only one representative of each telegram to be shown, and not all the tuples

[image]

Where it is marked all the values ​​from the messega bot table appear, if you have 50 tuples from the same Telegram group then you would have 50 options for you to choose from. How do you ensure there is only one representative? Example:
5X Group x, id =1;
10X Group y, id =2;

but only one of each appears:
Group x, id =1;
Group y, id =2;

code:

```
class MessageBot(models.Model):
  chat_id = models.BigIntegerField()
  chat_group = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
  date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  messageUser = models.TextField()

      self.client = client
      super().save(*args, **kwargs)

  def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.chat_id} - {self.chat_group}"
  
class MainGroup(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    telegram = models.ForeignKey('MessageBot', on_delete= models.CASCADE, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.telegram}"
```

**Edit:**

I'm trying to link the chat id of the message with the main group, that is, I want the main group not to be linked to the messagebot message but to the unique chat id of each group

Comment: The `telegram` field is a foreignkey to `MessageBot`. So when creating a `MainGroup`, all instances of `MessageBot` will be available. Do you want to just have one option of `MessageBot` to choose from? The example you gave is not clear enough, at least to me.

Comment: @Sam the question is not entirely clear. If you need to remove one field, like in the picture, then choose one of two self.chat_id or self.chat_group. For example: def __str__(self):
     return f"{self.chat_id}"

Comment: to everyone who commented: I'm trying to get the Main group to be linked to a chat id and not to a messagebot message. As it is, I can choose to link to any message, as if the messages were unique entities and they definitely are not, but the group in which they were sent are

Comment: @inquirer Create a response so that people can see this solution, I believe I have done something similar here: In MainGroup I redist that message with chat_id and chat_group (returns the name of the group) and only one message is saved. Would it be this?

Comment: @Sam to clarify, show several MessageBot and MainGroup records and show how you want to filter them (you can just manually write the lines to visually see what you need).

Comment: Is your **chat_id** from MessageBot unique (that is, there is only one such entry)? Just got the impression that **ForeignKey** should be in **MessageBot** since you want to get one telegram entry. Or judging by your last message, do you want to select entry by Chat_id and Chat_group?

Comment: o chat_id eh único por grupo de telegram, mas na tabela MessageBot ele recebe diversas mensagens então acaba que na tabela ele não eh único. I didn't quite understand your last question, but the messagebot is a class that receives the value sent by a bff